# React | Dynamic select get values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd

I'm using [ant design](https://ant.design/) for my react project.

In this, I need to add dynamic select and get values. Now I can able to select dropdown dynamically.

But I'm not able to get values.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        alert("Received values of form: ", values);
      }
    });
  };
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nrxq1505v0

Comment: I am able to get the value in console.log() but it's not working in alert for me.

Answer (score 2):

This will resolve your problem.

```
this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!err) {
    alert("Received values of form: " + values.names.join());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like below to get values

```
this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      const data = JSON.stringify(values);
      const d = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log("d...", d.names)//this gives values in an array. It prints like this ["lucy", "jack"] when I added two fields and seleted value from each field
      if (!err) {
        alert("Received values of form: ", d.names);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check all time your variable assign correct variable type or your expected variable using

```
console.log('comment', variable);
```

this is easy way, or you can debug your code

Please check working example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/7ymz953v7x).